# Recursively add 1 to all nodes in a BST except node with SMALLEST data

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to add +1 to every node's data except the node with the smallest number. So far, my implementation is not going correctly, I'm getting lost in the recursive calls. My code is adding incorrectly in some situations and not adding when necessary. I understand to find the smallest piece of data, we go to the node connected all the way left (8) in this case, am I missing certain test conditions?

```
Given a data set: 8, 14, 24, 29, 31, 35, 46, 58, 62,85, 95

Expected results: 8, 15, 25, 30, 32, 36, 47, 59, 63, 86, 96
Actual results: 9, 14, 25, 29, 32, 36, 46, 59, 63, 85, 96

struct node
{

 node * left;
 node * right;
 int data;

};

int add1(node * root) 
{

    if(!root) return 0;    
    add1(root->left); //go left

    if(!root->left)  { //if left is NULL
        if(root->right) //check if there is a right child
            add1(root->right); //go to that node
        else
            return 0;
    }

    root->data += 1;    //add 1 to node
    add1(root->right); //go right

return 1;
}

int main()
{
node * root = NULL;
build(root); //inserts data set into our tree

display(root);
add1(root);
display(root);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, did you mean to add the struct of my node?

Comment: yep node declaration and initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can descend the tree, keeping a track of whether or not you might be the left most node. If you ever took a right turn to reach a node, that node can't be leftmost. If you might be the leftmost node, and you have no left child, then you *are* the leftmost node. Everything else has 1 added.

```
void add1(root* node, bool mightbeLeftmost=true)
{
    if(!root) return;
    if(!mightbeLeftmost || root->left != nullptr) ++(root->data);
    add1(root->left, mightbeLeftmost);
    add1(root->right, false);
}

int main()
{
    //define list
    ...
    add1(root, true);
}
```

Comment: It's a binary search tree. You don't need to traverse the entire tree to discover the lowest value. The lowest value is always the leftmost value in the tree.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that part. Will adjust

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for the function with an extra benefit: in addition to incrementing all but the smallest value, it also returns the minimum BST value. It also works if minimum value is not unique.

```
#include <limits.h>

...

int add1(struct node* root)
{
        static int min;

        if (root == NULL)
          return INT_MAX;

        int lval = add1(root->left);

        // Check if it's the leftmost node to set min
        if (lval == INT_MAX)
            min = root->data;

        add1(root->right);

        if (root->data != min)
            root->data++;

        return min;
}
```